# Swift Package with different assets

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have a swift package, I want to use them in two different colour assets (others all same). Now the all files are in `/Sources`. What I am doing now is swap colour assets with another one. Is it possible to having two libraries, and they are sharing code but different assets. When I add with SPM to chose which library I use.

In my `PackageName` I have `extensions` for `Color`
I tried to create a new target like this

```
let package = Package(
    name: "PackageName",
    platforms: [
      .iOS(.v14)
    ],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(name: "Library1", targets: ["Library1"]),
        .library(name: "Library2", targets: ["Library2"])
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "PackageName"),
        .target(name: "Library1", dependencies: ["PackageName"] ,resources: [.process("Resources/Library1.xcassets")]),
        .target(name: "Library2", dependencies: ["PackageName"], resources: [.process("Resources/Library2.xcassets")])
    ]
)
```

But I can't use extension Color within PackageName.

I am expecting that when I add the package in SPM, I can choose one from two libraries and I can use those `Color` extensions I created in `PackageName`.